# Mercurial end of line translation

Tags: mercurial, cross-platform, eol

I'm using Mercurial on Windows for a cross-platform project, with the eol extension to translate line endings to Unix format, which mostly works, except .hgeol and .hgignore are not translated. My .hgeol  looks like this:

```
[patterns]
** = native
.* = native
```

where I got the ** line from the documentation, and then added .* just in case it works like the Unix shell expansion that otherwise ignores file names beginning with . but still no go. Is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: Why don't you just use Unix line endings in your editor?

Comment: I'm not confident Visual Studio will stay convinced to use Unix line endings, and even if I can so convince my installation thereof, I'm also thinking in terms of hopefully at a later date attracting more contributors.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly spelling out .hgeol and .hgignore as patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of `eol.py` explicitly disable translations for files starting with `.hg*`:

```
self.cfg.set('patterns', '.hg*', 'BIN')
```

If that is a problem for you, please open an issue in our bugtracker (I don't know why they chose to disable it for this files).